# Reassigning strings by value count in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a number of string-based columns in a `pandas` dataframe that I'm looking to use on `scikitlearn` classification models.  I know I have to use `oneHotEncoder` to properly encode the variables, but first, I want to reduce the variation in the columns, taking out either the strings that appear less than x% of the time in the column, or are not among the top x strings by count in the column.

Here's an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(22), 'b':list('aaaaaaaabbbbbbbcccdefg'), 'c':range(22)})
df1
     a  b   c
0    0  a   0
1    1  a   1
2    2  a   2
3    3  a   3
4    4  a   4
5    5  a   5
6    6  a   6
7    7  a   7
8    8  b   8
9    9  b   9
10  10  b  10
11  11  b  11
12  12  b  12
13  13  b  13
14  14  b  14
15  15  c  15
16  16  c  16
17  17  c  17
18  18  d  18
19  19  e  19
20  20  f  20
21  21  g  21
```

As you can see, a, b, and c appear in column b more than 10% of the time, so I'd like to keep them.  On the other hand, d, e, f, and g appear less than 10% (actually about 5% of the time), so I'd like to bucket these by changing them into 'other':

```
df1['b']
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     a
4     a
5     a
6     a
7     a
8     b
9     b
10    b
11    b
12    b
13    b
14    b
15    c
16    c
17    c
18    other
19    other
20    other
21    other
```

I'd similarly like to be able to say that I only want to keep the values that appear in the top 2 in terms of frequency, so that column b looks like this:

```
df1['b']
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     a
4     a
5     a
6     a
7     a
8     b
9     b
10    b
11    b
12    b
13    b
14    b
15    other
16    other
17    other
18    other
19    other
20    other
21    other
```

I don't see an obvious way to do this in Pandas, although I admittedly know a lot more about this in R.  Any ideas? Any thoughts on how to make this robust to Nones, which may appear more than 10% of the time or sit in the top x number of values?

Comment: What do you mean by "robust to Nones"?  Is the idea not to consider None when taking the denominator to determine the fraction?  (And do you mean `None`, the Python object, or `"None"`, the string, or `np.nan`?)

Comment: Yes, I mean `np.nan`.  I would ideally want to have the option, but if not, for the ranking to also count and consider the nones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is kinda contorted, but it's kind of a complicated question.

First, get the counts:

```
In [24]: sizes = df1["b"].value_counts()

In [25]: sizes
Out[25]: 
b
a    8
b    7
c    3
d    1
e    1
f    1
g    1
dtype: int64
```

Now, pick the indices you don't like:

```
In [27]: bad = sizes.index[sizes < df1.shape[0]*0.1]

In [28]: bad
Out[28]: Index([u'd', u'e', u'f', u'g'], dtype='object')
```

Finally, assign "other" to those rows containing bad indices:

```
In [34]: df1.loc[df1["b"].isin(bad), "b"] = "other"

In [36]: df1
Out[36]: 
     a      b   c
0    0      a   0
1    1      a   1
2    2      a   2
3    3      a   3
4    4      a   4
5    5      a   5
6    6      a   6
7    7      a   7
8    8      b   8
9    9      b   9
10  10      b  10
11  11      b  11
12  12      b  12
13  13      b  13
14  14      b  14
15  15      c  15
16  16      c  16
17  17      c  17
18  18  other  18
19  19  other  19
20  20  other  20
21  21  other  21

[22 rows x 3 columns]
```

You can use `sizes.sort()` and get the last `n` values from the result in order to find just the top two indices.

**Edit**: you should be able to do something like this, replacing all instances of "b" with `filterByColumn`:

```
def filterDataFrame(df1, filterByColumn):
    sizes = df1[filterByColumn].value_counts()
    ...
```

Comment: thanks! I actually made my own function to solve this (which I will share), but this looks much simpler.

Comment: also, any thoughts onto how to make what you suggested into a function, so I can repeat it on multiple columns?  I'm having trouble extracting the "b" and "df1" values in `df1.loc[df1["b"].isin(bad), "b"] = "other"` without having to ask the user to put in df1, df1["b"], and "b" as independent input parameters in the function.

Comment: see my edit above for a suggestion on how to start putting it together as a function; should actually be straightforward (just remember to make a copy at the beginning of the function if you don't want the original data frame to get edited!)

Comment: @Noah . Bryan..  Can you please explain how will you use this new feature for testing. Eg the test record can have one of the values we are keeping or from 'other' category. How to check this?

Comment: @MBack I'm not sure exactly what your question is; please open a new stackoverflow question so that you have enough space to ask the question properly

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
def cleanupData(inputCol, fillString, cutoffPercent=None, cutoffNum=31):
    col=inputCol
    col.fillna(fillString, inplace=True)
    valueCounts=col.value_counts()
    totalAmount=sum(valueCounts)
    if cutoffPercent is not None and cutoffNum is not None:
        raise NameError("both cutoff percent and number have values. Please only give one of these values")
    if cutoffPercent is not None:
        cutoffAmount=cutoffPercent*totalAmount
        valuesToKeep=valueCounts[valueCounts>cutoffAmount]
        valuesToKeep=valuesToKeep.index.tolist()
        numValuesKept=len(valuesToKeep)
        print "keeping "+str(numValuesKept)+" unique values in the returned column"
    if cutoffNum is not None:
        valueNames=valueCounts.index.tolist()
        valuesToKeep=valueNames[0:cutoffNum]
    newlist=[]
    for row in col:
        if any(row in element for element in valuesToKeep):
            newlist.append(row)
        else:
            newlist.append("Other")
    return newlist
##


cleanupData(df1['b'], "Other", cutoffNum=2)   
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other']
```

Answer (score 0):

assign your frame to variable (I call it x) and then count per value in the column "b"

```
d = {s: sum(x["b"].values==s) for s in set(x["b"].values)}
```

You can then use this mask to assign a new value if d[s] is below a certain threshold

```
x[x["b"].values==s] = "Call me Peter Maffay"
```

Comment: what do you mean by assigning my frame to variable? Do you mean the `pd.Categorical.from_array()` function?  Can you fit it into my example?

Comment: oh, sorry. You do this already. You call the variable df1. I call it x

Comment: However, use the value_counts() method as suggested above to construct the dictionary d